# UnsupportedClassVersionError with IBM Java 1.6.0 and maven 3.3.3

Tags: java, maven-3

I have environment with  IBM Java 1.6.0 and maven 3.3.3.

when I run **mvn clean install** I get below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli, offset=6
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:262)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:540)
```

Comment: You need to start using Maven Toolchain...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting the *System Requirements* from [Maven home page](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi):

```
Maven 3.3 requires JDK 1.7 or above to execute
```

1.6.0 (IBM or not) will not do.

Comment: When I changed to compiler and runtime to java 1.8 and try maven build it say's "No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?"

Comment: @MahenderReddyYasa Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK? Type `javac` in console - if it doesn't exist, you are.

Answer (score 0):

**From Javadocs :-**

*Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine attempts to read a class file and determines that the major and minor version numbers in the file are not supported.*

Try using a Java version which is supported by Maven.